# Java Monkey Engine (jME) - Physics Control

Tags: java, jmonkeyengine

I am new in jME (java Monkey Engine). I am doing my master project about a smart home simulator. I decided to do this project with jME.

Right now, I have a 3D model into my simulator, the next step I want to do It's control the main door of my virtual house, so, I followed this tutorial and I could implement exactly I wanted.

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNDiZ9YHIpM
```

I tried opening and closing the door, and I got. But the problem is the physics, when the door is opening you can see how the door is opening, but when I try to cross the door I can't , I know I can do a physics layer into the object but when I try to do this the control disapear.

I have a class which control my main door and I would like insert into that class a rigid body for my door but i can't, so i would like to know if someone know how do this.

Thank You!!!

PD: sorry for my english!!!

This is the code I am using:

Main Class

```
public class Main extends SimpleApplication
        implements ActionListener{

private GhostControl ghostControl;
  private Node staticScene,dynamicScene;
  private BulletAppState bulletAppState;
  private RigidBodyControl landscape;
  private OpenDoor rigidDoor;
  private CharacterControl player;
  private Vector3f walkDirection = new Vector3f();
  private boolean left = false, right = false, up = false, down = false;

  Spatial mainDoor;
  OpenDoor control;

  HUD hud = new HUD();
  BitmapText hudText;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main app = new Main();
     //some presets
    AppSettings settings = new AppSettings(true);
    settings.setResolution(1280,720);
    settings.setFrameRate(60);
    //settings.setFullscreen(true);
    app.setSettings(settings);
    //app.setShowSettings(false);
    app.setPauseOnLostFocus(true);
    app.start();
  }

  public void simpleInitApp() {   
    //don't show stats
    setDisplayFps(false);
    setDisplayStatView(false);

    //PIC
    Picture pic = new Picture("HUD Picture");
    pic.setImage(assetManager, "Textures/hudFrame.png", true);
    pic.setWidth(settings.getWidth());
    pic.setHeight(settings.getHeight()/8);
    pic.setPosition(0,settings.getHeight()-settings.getHeight()/8);
    guiNode.attachChild(pic);
    //Show HUD


    hudText = new BitmapText(guiFont, false);   
    hudText.setSize(guiFont.getCharSet().getRenderedSize());      // font size
    hudText.setSize(settings.getHeight()/45);
    hudText.setColor(ColorRGBA.Green);                             // font color
    hudText.setLocalTranslation(settings.getWidth()/45,settings.getHeight()-settings.getHeight()/45, 0); // 
    guiNode.attachChild(hudText);

    hud = new HUD();

    /** Set up Physics */
    bulletAppState = new BulletAppState();
    bulletAppState.setThreadingType(BulletAppState.ThreadingType.PARALLEL);//for bullets
    stateManager.attach(bulletAppState);
    //bulletAppState.getPhysicsSpace().enableDebug(assetManager);
    // We re-use the flyby camera for rotation, while positioning is handled by physics
    viewPort.setBackgroundColor(new ColorRGBA(0.7f, 0.8f, 1f, 1f));
    flyCam.setMoveSpeed(100);
    setUpKeys();
    setUpLight();

    //Preload Levels

    staticScene = (Node) assetManager.loadModel("Scenes/newScene.j3o");
    staticScene.setLocalScale(5f);

    //Intentamos hacer lo mismo pero a partir de un nodo del modelo
    mainDoor = (Spatial)staticScene.getChild("MainDoor-ogremesh");    




    //Set up physics and add level/player to scenegraph

    setDoor(mainDoor);
    setLevel(staticScene);    

  }

  private void setLevel(Spatial level) {
     // We set up collision detection for the scene by creating a
    // compound collision shape and a static RigidBodyControl with mass zero.
    CollisionShape sceneShape =
            CollisionShapeFactory.createMeshShape((Node) level);

    landscape = new RigidBodyControl(sceneShape, 0);  
    level.addControl(landscape);

    // We set up collision detection for the player by creating
    // a capsule collision shape and a CharacterControl.
    // The CharacterControl offers extra settings for
    // size, stepheight, jumping, falling, and gravity.
    // We also put the player in its starting position.
    CapsuleCollisionShape capsuleShape = new CapsuleCollisionShape(1.5f, 6f, 1);
    player = new CharacterControl(capsuleShape, 0.05f);
    player.setJumpSpeed(20);
    player.setFallSpeed(30);
    player.setGravity(30);
    player.setPhysicsLocation(new Vector3f(20,10,-10));
    // We attach the scene and the player to the rootnode and the physics space,
    // to make them appear in the game world.
    rootNode.attachChild(level);
    bulletAppState.getPhysicsSpace().add(landscape);
    bulletAppState.getPhysicsSpace().add(player); 


  }

  public void setDoor(Spatial door){

    CollisionShape sceneDoor =
            CollisionShapeFactory.createMeshShape((Node)door);

    rigidDoor = new OpenDoor(sceneDoor, 0);
    rigidDoor.setKinematic(true);

    door.addControl(rigidDoor);
    bulletAppState.getPhysicsSpace().add(door); 

  }

  private PhysicsSpace getPhysicsSpace() {
        return bulletAppState.getPhysicsSpace();
  }

  private void setUpLight() {
    // We add light so we see the scene
    AmbientLight al = new AmbientLight();
    al.setColor(ColorRGBA.White.mult(0.1f));
    rootNode.addLight(al);

    DirectionalLight dl = new DirectionalLight();
    dl.setColor(ColorRGBA.White);
    dl.setDirection(new Vector3f(1.5f, -2, 2).normalizeLocal());
    rootNode.addLight(dl);
  }

  /** We over-write some navigational key mappings here, so we can
   * add physics-controlled walking and jumping: */
  private void setUpKeys() {
    inputManager.deleteMapping(INPUT_MAPPING_EXIT);
    inputManager.addMapping("Left", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_A));
    inputManager.addMapping("Right", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_D));
    inputManager.addMapping("Up", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_W));
    inputManager.addMapping("Down", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_S));
    inputManager.addMapping("Jump", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_SPACE));
    inputManager.addMapping("Action", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_E));
    inputManager.addMapping("Quit", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_ESCAPE));
    inputManager.addListener(this, "Left");
    inputManager.addListener(this, "Right");
    inputManager.addListener(this, "Up");
    inputManager.addListener(this, "Down");
    inputManager.addListener(this, "Jump");
    inputManager.addListener(actionListener,"Action");
    inputManager.addListener(this, "Quit"); // listen for ESC key to close game
  }

  public void onAction(String binding, boolean value, float tpf) {

    hud.setToken(binding);

    if (binding.equals("Left")) {
      if (value) { left = true; } else { left = false; }
    } else if (binding.equals("Right")) {
      if (value) { right = true; } else { right = false; }
    } else if (binding.equals("Up")) {
      if (value) { up = true; } else { up = false; }
    } else if (binding.equals("Down")) {
      if (value) { down = true; } else { down = false; }
    } else if (binding.equals("Jump")) {
      player.jump();
    } else if (binding.equals("Quit")) {
      stop(); // simple way to close game
    } 
  }

  private ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
    public void onAction(String name, boolean keyPressed, float tpf) {
      if (name.equals("Action") && !keyPressed) {
         rigidDoor.actionDoor();

      }
    }
  };


  @Override
  public void simpleUpdate(float tpf) {

        Vector3f camDir = cam.getDirection().clone().multLocal(0.6f);
        Vector3f camLeft = cam.getLeft().clone().multLocal(0.4f);
        walkDirection.set(0, 0, 0);
        if (left)  { walkDirection.addLocal(camLeft); }
        if (right) { walkDirection.addLocal(camLeft.negate()); }
        if (up)    { walkDirection.addLocal(camDir); }
        if (down)  { walkDirection.addLocal(camDir.negate()); }
        player.setWalkDirection(walkDirection);
        cam.setLocation(player.getPhysicsLocation());  
  }


}
```

DoorControl Class

```
    public class OpenDoor extends RigidBodyControl{

    static final float PI = 3.14159265359f;    
    private float speed = 5;
    private float inipos = 0f;
    private boolean action = false; //true=opening, false=closing
    RigidBodyControl myRigidBody;

    public OpenDoor() {

    }

    public OpenDoor(CollisionShape sceneDoor, int i) {
        super(sceneDoor,i);

    }

    @Override
    public void update(float tpf) {
        super.update(tpf);
        Quaternion q = new Quaternion();
        q.fromAngles(0, -tpf, 0);

        spatial.rotate(q); 



        /*float angle;
        float angleRads;
        angle = speed;
        angleRads = (angle * PI)/180;
        if(action==true){
            //counter = counter + angleRads;
            if(Math.abs(spatial.getLocalRotation().getY()*2.2-inipos)<PI/2){
                spatial.rotate(0, -angleRads,0); 

            }

        }else{

            if(spatial.getLocalRotation().getY()*2.2-inipos<0){
            spatial.rotate(0, angleRads,0);
            }            

        }          

*/
    }

    /**
     * @return the speed
     */
    public float getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    /**
     * @param speed the speed to set
     */
    public void setSpeed(float speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    /**
     * @return the action
     */
    public boolean isAction() {
        return action;
    }

    /**
     * @param action the action to set
     */
    public void setAction(boolean action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public boolean getAction() {
        return action;
    }

    public void actionDoor(){

       setAction(!action);

    }

    public Object getRigidDoor() {
        return myRigidBody;
    }



}
```

Comment: Could you post an entire (short) program that replicates the problem. Preferably without any external resources e.g. use boxes rather than imported geometries

Comment: It's not important that the program works (in fact then there would be no question) just that it demonstrates the problem. If we can run a program and see the problem it's much easier for us to help

Comment: Sorry, i am new with this, and I was yesterday try to do the short program, but I don't now how is do.

In my app, I have got a scene with my models, and I connect one Node of my scene (Door Node) with one Node on my code. On the other hand, I have created a class which implements a RigirDoorControl Class to create moviment in my door, In this class I have an update method which I move my door. The moviment of my door is working, but the Physics is not working.

Comment: This is a link with my project, Thanks!!!

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56830878/DoorTest.rar

Comment: Is the code that replicates this problem too big for the question itself?

Comment: No, the code its just the main class and the class called OpenDoor, there are a method into the main class called setDoor(Spatial door), I think the problem is for this way.

Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Ok, put that code in the question and we'll be able to have a look

Comment: I think the problem is into the method called setDoor

Comment: Hmm, I'm somewhat unsure, however 1 issue I can see if that you are setting the kinematics mass as 0, that means its static, which it is not. Changing that does not seem to solve the problem however

Comment: Yeahh, I've got it, The problem was that I had to scale the Spatial, I 've showed the debug mode  and I could solve it.  


Thank you show much, I've been two days with this.

If I can do something for you please ask me.

Comment: Are you sure, I just found the problem and it was that you needed to put a node inbetween the geometry and the root node and use the node as your physics Node rather than the geometry itself

Comment: Yes, I have been testing all the day and that is exactly I did. Thank You!!!